# C# MessageBox For All Items In Array

Tags: c#, arrays, messagebox

I am trying to iterate through an array of strings and present all of them in a single messagebox. The code I have at the minute is this:

```
string[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
foreach(item in array)
{
   MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

This obviously brings up a messagebox for each item, is there any way I can show them all at once in a messagebox outside the loop? I will be using \n to separate the items if this is possible, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine the individual strings from the array into a single string (such as with the [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method) and then display the concatenated string:

```
string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array); 
MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `string.Join` to make them into one string. Don't, use `\n`, it's better to use `Environment.NewLine`

```
string msg = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would see two common ways to do this.

```
        // Short and right on target
        string[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
        string output = string.Join("\n", array);
        MessageBox.Show(output);


        // For more extensibility.. 
        string output = string.Empty;
        string[] array = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        foreach (var item in array) {
            output += item + "\n"; 
        }

        MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

try Using this..

```
using System.Threading;



string[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};


        foreach (var item in array)
        {

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item);
            }).Start();


        }
```

Comment: This isn't what he asked. Even if it was, don't do this

Comment: Not only does this not show the items in a single `MessageBox` separated by `\n`, you are showing UI on threads other than the UI thread. That is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put the message box out of the loop like this

```
string[] array = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

string message5 = "";

foreach (var item in rates)
{
    message5 += item + "\n" ;
  
}
MessageBox.Show(message5);
```